# Can't compile using "gcc"

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I want to compile programs using Linux commands, in Windows, without needing to install Ubuntu. I installed Cygwin, and I followed this tutorial( http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41382/how-to-use-linux-commands-in-windows-with-cygwin/ ) in order to get it to work on Windows, and it works( or at least it worked for ls command). The problem is that when I try to use gcc function to compile a program, it says that it's not recognized as a command. Is there any other way to compile a program?

Edit:
  Here it's a picture of how it looks.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an extremely complicated setup for a compilation environment. Anyway, you will have to tell us more precisely what the issue is. If a command like `ls` works for you, then where is the difference to a `gcc` command? Find out where the executable is located and post the full and exact error message.

Comment: First of all `gcc` is not a function, it's a shell command to invoke the GNU C compiler. If it isn't recognized, then it probably can't be found in the expected place.

Comment: Did you make sure to check `gcc` during the package selection stage? Cygwin only installs a limited set of packages by default, and you have to select anything else you want explicitly. Also, just to be clear, Cygwin compiles with Linux-like commands but *for Windows*. Cygwin binaries are for Windows, Linux.

Comment: Gcc is an optional application on the cygwin setup.exe install menu.

Comment: bin folder set to PATH

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure about package of gcc installed or not, then install additional package "devel default" package which comes with all your Linux compilation Shell commands..hope it works for you
If not then there is an another method for running Linux command in windows..check above and comment...

Comment: Cygwin has no equivalent of a typical Linux development package.  You would choose gcc g++ make etc individually. There are also "cross " gcc etc targeting mingw not using linux posix emulation.

Answer (score 0):

run the `setup` command that comes with `cygwin`.

When looking at the available optional items, find the `gcc` command.  Select it (and all lower level items)

Then complete the run of the `setup` command.

Comment: "setup" is not recognized either.

Comment: he means `https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe` or `https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe` depending on your architecture

Comment: the edited question shows back slashes in the directory path and does not show YOUR cygwin login directory.  So your not actually running cygwin correctly.   Suggest reading: `https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/cygwin/`  for details on how it should be done.